# android - difference between running process and cached background process

Tags: processes

In my running processes,

camera has 1 process and 0 services running. I don't have it open in the foreground so why wouldn't this be a cached background process? How can there be a live process if the app isn't in the foreground?

Could someone clear this up for me?